# Cucumber/Capybara/Selenium - Setting the cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, cucumber, capybara

For my test case, I tried setting the cookies with following ways, But it is not getting set

```
1)browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  browser.manage.add_cookie :name => "xxx", :value => "cookie"

2)driver = Capybara.current_session.driver
  br = driver.browser.send(:bridge)
  br.addCookie({
    'name'    => "xxx",
    'domain'  => "localhost",
    'value'   => "cookie",
    'path'    => '/',
    'expires' => (Time.now + 100.years).to_i
  })
```

Let me know if i miss anything or i have to do it in other way

Comment: First variant looks good to me. Please elaborate on what you mean by `it is not getting set`

Comment: Works for me, though I called it with `page.driver.browser.manage.add_cookie()`.

Comment: It strongly depends on the actual driver: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17244628/651651.

Answer (score 2):

Capybara has to visit the website you're testing first. It is a required step before you can set any cookie.

This works:

```
visit '/'
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.manage.add_cookie name: "name", value: "value"
```

For best performance, either run this step just once, or see if the cookie is already set. Here is actual code that sets the `cookieconsent` cookie, which bypasses a cookie wall.

```
browser = page.driver.browser
unless browser.manage.cookie_named("cookieconsent")
  visit '/'
  browser.manage.add_cookie name: "cookieconsent", value: "dismiss"
end
```

I am using `page.driver` to get the driver. It's the same thing as `Capybara.current_session.driver`.